# Control content of "off the top" scrolling on Mac browsers?

Tags: macos, webkit

Is it possible to control the content of the content — normally a grey linen — which is "under" the page on Webkit-based Mac browsers?

[image: example of the scroll-off region]

For example, I'd like to extend an image on my page "above the top" of the page, so Mac users who scroll off the top get to see some additional content.

Comment: That would be cool. Pretty sure it's not possible. Maybe ask at webkit.org? Or file a bug report?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible in WebKit-based browsers. The linen texture in the overhang area is not configurable in any way.